# Does it affect the performance, if a table holds a lot of unused/unselected columns?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

**Background:**
I have a table called cars that holds a lot of used cars, aprox 1 million rows. The table has a little more than 170 columns. The table is indexed on individual columns alone. Most of the columns are booleans (e.g. has_automatic_gearbox etc.) and the rest is strings and numbers (e.g. color and price). The cars are shown in a view, where i use around 80 columns out of the total 170.

**My question:**
So my question is, does it make a difference to the performance, whether I select only the 80 columns out of the table when doing a search, or on the other hand I made a new table ONLY consisting of those 80 columns that I need, instead of the total 170 columns? So in other words, does it make a difference to performance, that a table holds columns, that is not selected?

Comment: As with most performance questions, the answer is "it depends".  Why not benchmark your two proposed solutions?

Comment: Well it's complicated to get it tested in production. Depends on what? this must be a pretty easy question to answer if you have the right knowledge, since all factors are constant, except for the number of unused columns.

Comment: A table itself is never "slow" or "fast" - queries are. A query getting all 170 columns is definitely going to be slower than a query getting only 80 of them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's not my question, I am NOT selecting ALL 170 rows in the first example. My question is simply, if it makes a difference if I ONLY had those 80 columns in a table without the rest. I would be selecting the same columns, and the table would be setup in the exact same way, just without the unused columns.

Comment: @NielsKristian I think you need to read more about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal Another comment I was expecting to hear, but doesn't really answer the question :-) That was why I wrote what the columns consists of. Cause how would you normalize a boolean??? That doesn't make sense. And what would you gain from normalizing the price of the color, except for worse performance from all the joins you would need to do????

Comment: PostGre reads table rows by reading 'pages' of data from disk at a time.  The larger the row size, the less rows can be stored in each page. If the page size was the same for both tables, queries directed at the smaller table would require less page reads to get the row data to be returned  (i.e. the difference would be 20 page reads with 200 rows each, or 10 page reads with 400 rows each), so there could possibly be a fractional improvement to speed. This improvement would probably be so small that it would be overshadowed by other factors, such as concurrent disk accesses, cache hits etc.

Comment: If you're looking for a definitive "yes, extra columns hurt performance everywhere" so that you are justified in going and removing them, then you're going to be disappointed.  Performance is many things.  Are you asking about performance when selecting?  Updating?  Inserting?  Maybe you're concerned about disk space.  There is no pat answer here that covers everything.

Comment: @AndyLester Well, as i wrote: "(...) whether I select only (...)" :-)

Comment: Note that indexing single boolean columns is unlikely to yield a performance benefit.  Indexes work well when they help you get to a row fast.  If half the values in the index are true and half false, then the index serves little purpose.  If 90% are true (and 10% false), then it might help find the rows with false quicker, but it does nothing for rows that are true; it would be quicker to ignore the index and do a table scan (almost invariably).  Indexes should have decent selectivity; there should be many distinct key values (and two is not 'many').

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Valid point!

Comment: @MahmoudGamal I would like your thoughts on this one, if you have any (I started a bounty)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345015/rails-activerecord-and-db-normalization

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: True. Boolean columns can still be very useful in the `WHERE` clause of a [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html). Niels might benefit from following this link to the manual.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Andomar is correct in his comment that "it depends". However, if you question is something like this:

> Can the number of columns in a table have an effect upon select queries?

Then the answer is **YES**. Whether or not they're "extra" or "unused" is a question of database design, and doesn't have anything to do with the question of performance.

All other things being equal, a row in a table with 100 columns is going to take up more space than a row in a table with 10 columns. Because the rows will be larger, your server will have to work (relatively) harder to go over an equal number of rows in the wider table than in the smaller table.

Things like page splitting will also occur more often in tables whose rows take up more space.

If your question is (and I think this might be more along the lines of what you're asking)

> Would, all things being equal, a select query pulling 80 columns from a table with 170 columns be slower than a query pulling 80 columns from a table with 80 columns?

Then the answer should be **NO**.

Comment: The bigger tablesize will only matter if a table scan is used. For index scans the total size of the table won't have an effect on the query. So I'd say it's not a (clear) a **YES**. It's a **YES, but...** answer ("it depends...")

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'm referring to the size of each row, not the size of the table. Larger rows take up more space, and (again, all things being equal) larger rows mean more pages and slower performance.

Comment: The last one is the right one, that was where I was trying to get to :-) I know that the first part is true, but thats another thing.

Comment: Don't forget that your second 80 column table won't be free to create.  You need to factor in how you're going to keep the second table up to date, whether you rebuild it or use triggers etc, and compare that to how often your query will use it.

Comment: @Gary: What 80-column table are you referring to?

Comment: @Adam Robinson:  The OP wanted to know if selecting 80 columns from a 170 column table is slower than selecting 80 columns from a hand made 80 column table specific for reporting.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: The second part of your answer (where you say NO) is strictly incorrect. Why? Read the first part of your answer! And read more under [this related question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18864/3684). All things are never "equal", NO is always incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Also you may want to read the answers to a [similar question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18864/what-is-retrieved-from-disk-during-a-query) on dba.SE:

> ```
> Do the number of columns in a particular table affect the performance
> of a query, when querying on a subset of that table?
> ```

In short: yes it does, because the non-selected columns generally live in the same disk blocks than the selected columns, so they're going to be read anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the attributes of your 1E6 cars will probably depend on some hidden factor, such as  {brand,model,make,model_version}. You could queeze out these attributes into a separate table, and refer to that table in your main cars table. In the ultimate case, your main cars table will only contain attributes that belong to the particular *instance* of a car model (eg: {number, price, build_date, buy_date, (maybe) colour}.)

Comment: Thanks, have a go one this one if you like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345015/rails-activerecord-and-db-normalization

Comment: Sorry I cannot read that. It is all gibberish to me. (IMHO with ill-defined semantics,too)