# Return true if all column values are true

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, exists, boolean-logic

Is there a faster way in PostgreSQL to essentially do an if on several rows?

Say I have a table

```
ticket | row | archived
1      | 1   | true
1      | 2   | true
1      | 3   | true
2      | 1   | false
2      | 2   | true
```

Is there any way I could do an if statement across down the column where ticket = ?
So that where ticket = 1 would be true because

```
true && true && true = true
```

and where ticket = 2 would be false because

```
false && true = false
```

Or should I just stick with

```
SELECT ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE ticket = 1)
       = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE ticket = 1 AND archived = true) )
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### Aggregate function [`bool_and()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

Simple, short, clear:

```
SELECT bool_and(archived)
FROM   tbl
WHERE  ticket = 1;
```

[The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

> true if all input values are true, otherwise false

#### Subquery expression [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS)

Assuming `archived` is defined `NOT NULL`. Faster, but you have to additionally check whether any rows with `ticket = 1` exist at all, or you'll get incorrect results for non-existing tickets:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT FROM tbl WHERE ticket=1)
       AND NOT
       EXISTS (SELECT FROM tbl WHERE ticket=1 AND NOT archived);
```

#### Indices

Both forms can use an index like:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_ticket_idx ON tbl (ticket);
```

.. which makes both fast, but the `EXISTS` query *faster*, because this form can stop to scan as soon as the first matching row is found. Hardly matters for only few rows per ticket, but matters for many.

To make use of **index-only scans** you need a [**multi-column index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) of the form:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_ticket_archived_idx ON tbl (ticket, archived);
```

This one is **better** in most cases and any version of PostgreSQL. Due to [data alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860), adding a `boolean` to the `integer` in the index will not make the index grow at all. Added benefit for hardly any cost.
Update: this changes in Postgres 13 with index deduplication. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

However, indexed columns prevent HOT (Heap Only Tuple) updates. Say, an `UPDATE` changes only the column `archived`. If the column isn't used by any index (in any way), the row can be HOT updated. Else, this shortcut cannot be taken. More on HOT updates:

- [Redundant data in update statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806058/redundant-data-in-update-statements/7806610#7806610)

It all depends on your actual workload.

Comment: Definitely a clean solution!  Curious how the perf is, and can it take advantage of index-only scans in 9.2?

Comment: @Mike: I dug a little deeper, ran some tests and added a bit about indexes and performance to my answer.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I appreciate your time to answer! I'm accepting Erwin's answer though, because the much shorter code will sit better in my query! The performance hit shouldn't be too much, I don't expect this query to run on more than a few rows per ticket.
Thanks guys!

Comment: @mouckatron: I added a bit about HOT updates. Might be of interest to you, if you have lots of `UPDATE`s.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I'm always impressed with your knowledge of Postgres. I upvoted dozens of your answers by now.

Answer (score 5):

How about something like:

```
select not exists (select 1 from table where ticket=1 and not archived)
```

I think this might be advantageous over comparing the counts, as a `count` [may or may not use an index](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting) and really all you need to know is if *any* `FALSE` rows exist for that ticket.  I think just creating a partial index on `ticket` could be incredibly fast.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/84a65/4)

Comment: Count will not use an index *if* it is a version of PostgreSQL prior to 9.2.  Just learned that recently.

Comment: @JayC: of course count() can use an index. `select count(*) from foo where some_col = 1` can use an index on some_col if that doesn't return too many rows. `count()` will not use an index if you are counting ***all*** rows in a table (without any restrictions)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Oh thanks for clearing that up!  I was a bit curious after [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014277/why-is-this-count-query-so-slow) recent question, which I see you also commented on.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: you are right; I shouldn't have let Mike confuse me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
select not false = any (
        select archived
        from foo
        where ticket = 1
    )
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/84a65/9)