# Do unselected columns in a SQL Table slow down a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, say I have columns A,B,C in Table X. If I use the query "Select A, B from X", would that query be any slower than if I delete column C and just do "Select * from X"

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12603163/9406040) to a similar question

Answer (score 4):

The performance of a query on a single table that selects all rows is pretty much driven by the I/O cost.  The I/O cost, in turn, is based on the number of data pages read by the query.

In general, having an additional column will increase the size of rows.  Fewer rows fit on fewer pages, so the query could be a bit faster.

Now for caveats.  Here are some:

- If `C` is a varchar that is always `NULL`, it occupies no extra space.
- If `C` is `varchar(max)` (or really large) it might be stored on a separate data page.
- If an index exists with `(A, B)` (in either order), then the query should use the index.  Because the index covers the query, the number of data pages is irrelevant.
- SQL Server does look aheads on I/O and can interleave I/O with other processing.  So, you might not notice the additional CPU time spend reading the data pages.

I wouldn't be inclined to simply remove columns to speed up such a query, unless the columns are not being used.  The increase in speed -- if any -- is likely to be small.  But there may exist cases where that would be a good idea from a performance perspective.

Comment: Also, the columns selected can influence the execution plan and performance. In the case of select queries that return data to the client, network performance is a consideration.

Comment: @DanGuzman . . . If I understand the question, the same columns are being returned.  It is only about the representation of the data in the database.